# Search for a number more than 9 while reading a file

Tags: java

```java
String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Search for a number from 0-9");
    int intNum = Integer.parseInt(str);
    try {
        File file = new File("numbers.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        int num;
        int count = 0;
        int position = 1;
        while ((num = br.read()) != -1) {
            if (Character.getNumericValue(num) == intNum) {
                System.out.println(intNum + " occurred in " + position + " digit");
                count++;
            }
            position++;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                intNum + " was found " + count + " times in " + position + " digits", "Result",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

numbers.txt is a text file contains more than thousands of numbers. With this code I can only search for values from 0-9, is there any way that I can search for number 10,11,12...

**Clarification:** I want to **search** for a number in another number (e.g, there are 2 occurences of 45 in 1*45*6*45*2)

Comment: If you just need to find numbers, [use regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) instead of looking at individual chars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For finding numbers bigger than 9**

Using BufferedReader is perfectly fine:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your/file/path"))) {
  String s;
  while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] s1 = s.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
      if (s1[i].matches("\\d+")) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(s1[i]);
        if (num > 9) {
          System.out.println("Found number bigger than 9 (" + num + ")");
        }
      }
    }
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  //log
}
```

`br.readLine()` reads the next line. Split the line by spaces, then check every word in the line for a number. If the word is a number (verified with the regex `\\d+`), parse then check if it's greater than 9.

Then again `Scanner` does make the job a lot much easier:

```
Scanner scanner;
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(new File("your/file/path"));
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int cur = scanner.nextInt();
            if(cur > 9) {
                System.out.println("Found number bigger than 9 ("+cur+")");
            }
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**For searching for a number in another number**

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your/file/path"))){
    String s;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lookFor = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    String read = br.readLine();
    int len = String.valueOf(lookFor).length();
    int found = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i+len < read.length(); i++) {
        String cur = read.substring(i, i+len);
        if(Integer.parseInt(cur)==lookFor) {
            found++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Found: "+found);
```

Although since you mentioned that the text file contains billions of digits I would like to note that the maximum characters that a `String` can hold is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. If you get an `OutOfMemoryException` it's because there are too many digits.

Comment: the text file is only one line

Comment: @ErFy "contains more than thousands of numbers" - are you sure?

Comment: @ErFy Also, why does it make that much of a difference if it's only 1 line?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are in one line.

Comment: @ErFy The code works if the file has 1 line or 1000. Number of lines shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: because I will then search for a value inside millions of numbers

Comment: @ErFy I don't get it. What are you trying to say when you say "the text file is only one line"?

Comment: It is a pi digit text file with one line, I want to be able to search for example number 22 as an input and give me the result of how many 22s happened in the text file. I have wrote the code and it works fine but it only works for numbers from 0-9 as input.

Comment: @ErFy Could you please provide a sample of the text file in your question? (e.g, edit it to include the first 50 characters or so)

Comment: 14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270

it is billions of digits in one line, I can't paste it all

Comment: @ErFy What do you want me to do? Find every number bigger than 9 in the number?

Comment: No, if you run my code it will ask you to input a number, that number in my code can only be from 0-9, but I want to be able to input >=0. For example I need to enter/search for number 50, so how many times number 50 happened in the text file(please run my code and you will understand that you can't input a number which is more than 9, I guess it is because of characters)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I wanted.

Comment: @ErFy Glad to help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231438/discussion-between-erfy-and-spectric).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using just BufferedReader you could use something more fancy that allows you to read entire integer, not just a single character, for example Scanner.

There is a Scanner.nextInt() method you can find here:

https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/scanner

(You could also read line-by-line and parse integers on your own.)

Comment: I don't think you understood OP's question. He wants to find every occurrence of a number in another number. (e.g, find 45 in 1456). Your answer doesn't solve the issue at all.

Comment: Well, it was not quite clear that this is what OP wants from the original question asked. Possibly OP meant "thousands of digits", not " thousands of numbers"? If that's the case, then I agree it's a bit different question that requires different solution.

Comment: I would recommend editing your answer to preserve the upvotes and to make sure your answer doesn't get deleted for not answering the question.